# PLSQL trigger not working 0 rows inserted

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

Whatever I do to the trigger always returns "0 rows inserted". 
It is like it can't find the new values after inserting them. 
After adding the exception it return no_data_found and i don't know why.

```
before insert or update of rent_date, return_date on rent
for each row
declare

pragma AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

v_rentDate date;
v_returnDate date;


begin
 select rent_date 
   into v_rentDate
   from rent
  where rent_date = :new.rent_date;


  select return_date
    into v_returnDate
    from rent
   where return_date = :new.return_date;


if v_returnDate < v_rentDate then
  raise_application_error(-20158, 'Return date must be after the rent date');
else
  dbms_output.put_line('TEST');
end if;

  exception when no_data_found then raise_application_error(-20157, 'No data found');

end;
/


insert into rent values (82,sysdate-5,101,sysdate,sysdate+5,100);
--0 rows inserted
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're doing it the wrong way. Here's why:

- you are trying to select values from a table you're currently inserting into (or updating existing values)
- Oracle complains that it can't do that because the table is mutating
- in order to "fix" it, you used pragma `autonomous_transaction` which isolates trigger code from the main transaction

You shouldn't use that pragma for such a purpose. Lucky you, trigger can be rewritten in a simpler manner, the one that doesn't cause the mutating table error. As you want to compare `rent_date` and `return_date`, do it directly. Here's an example (see line #5):

```
SQL> create table rent
  2    (id           number,
  3     rent_date    date,
  4     return_date  date
  5    );

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_biu_rent
  2    before insert or update on rent
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if :new.return_date < :new.rent_date then
  6       raise_application_error (-20158, 'Return date must be after the rent date');
  7    end if;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> -- This will fail
SQL> insert into rent (id, rent_date, return_date) values
  2    (1, date '2019-05-25', date '2019-04-10');
insert into rent (id, rent_date, return_date) values
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20158: Return date must be after the rent date
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_BIU_RENT", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_BIU_RENT'


SQL> -- This is OK
SQL> insert into rent (id, rent_date, return_date) values
  2    (1, date '2019-03-28', date '2019-10-20');

1 row created.

SQL>
```